# Visual Studio 2019 move text selection horizontally similar to keyboard shortcut for moving vertically [Alt + ↑] and [Alt + ↓]

Tags: visual-studio

in VS2019 you can **move** a text line up and down by using [Alt + ↑] and [Alt + ↓] keys combination.
Is there a way to move a selected text horizontally inside one text line(right to left and left to right)?

PS: **MOVE** is not CUT&PASTE and should be done easily using only the keyboard

[image]

Comment: just `cut`, `ctrl+right` or `ctrl+left` to move cursor to next "word", then `paste`

Answer (score 2):

You can create the following command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension to move selected text one char right (C# language):

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    EnvDTE.TextSelection ts = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
    int selectionLength = ts.Text.Length;
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Cut");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CharRight");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
    ts.CharLeft(true, selectionLength);
}
```

And then assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mouse dragging enabled (See `Tools > Options > Text Editor > General > Drag and Drop text editing`), just click and drag the highlighted text to where you want it placed.

As for keyboard versions, Cut/Paste is the way to go. You can make it a little faster by using `Ctrl+Left/Right` to navigate the caret to each punctuation instead of each character.